# What is the best ETL tool within ArcGIS standard to bring CSV to an existing schema with domains and other constraints?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data, fields-attributes, interoperability

We will be bringing some GPS related data from a business partner to our existing schema. We have provided them the sample data and data model from ArcGIS Diagrammer. There are bunch of data import options available in ArcMap and ArcCatalog. I am looking for an efficient approach to finish the ETL process with proper messaging about the exceptions of domains, datatype and mandatory/non-mandatory - so that any novice user of ArcMap can follow it. I don't want any third party tool or code development, but I can build a model, if there are 2-3 tools involved. I am new to data interoperability - has anyone used it in similar situation. 
-Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using [arcpy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/) (Python programming) but since you are not comfortable with that, I'd suggest [ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000001000000). It has GUI and the learning curve is not very steep. You will be using several geoprocessing tools within ArcGIS and chain them within a visual canvas (a bit like MS Visio). The result of one tool's run will become an input for the next one in the chain. You can report errors, handle them and build quite sophisticated [if-else-then-while](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_advanced_techniques_in_ModelBuilder/002w0000005q000000/) logic within ModelBuilder with no coding at all.

PS. If you think your model might get larger with the time, I recommend invest in learning arcpy and Python which will let you create a more elegant, maintenable and scalable solution.

Comment: I can use Arcpy but timeline is the key. Also I am looking for more of a workflow to resolve my problem.